# async Task is being executed immediately instead of asynchronously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, task

I have a Task that should execute asynchronously that is executing synchronously. I'm not entirely sure why it's happening, and it seems to follow the example from [Microsoft's TAP model doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

```
    private T payload;
    private Func<Task<T>> updateFn;
    private Task updateTask = null;

    public async Task<TResult> Get<TResult>(bool force = false)
    {
        updateTask = Update();
        await updateTask;
        return payload;
    }

    private async Task Update()
    {
        try {
            payload = await updateFn();
            lastFetch = timeService.UTCNow;
            logger.Info($"Updated on {timeService.Now}");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            updateTask = null;
        }
    }
// ... 
// the updateFn is of type: async () => await networkRequestFunction
```

so what I expect to happen is ( `// #1` indicates order of execution )

```
public async Task<TResult> Get<TResult>(bool force = false)
{
    updateTask = Update(); // #1, #3 - updateTask set to Update
    await updateTask; // #4
    return payload; // #6
}

private async Task Update()
{
    try {
        payload = await updateFn(); // #2
        lastFetch = timeService.UTCNow; // #5...
        logger.Info($"Updated on {timeService.Now}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        updateTask = null; // #5 ends
    }
}
```

but what I'm observing is

```
public async Task<TResult> Get<TResult>(bool force = false)
{
    updateTask = Update(); // #1, #4 updateTask is set to Update, which is already completed
    await updateTask; // #5
    return payload; // #6
}

private async Task Update()
{
    try {
        payload = await updateFn(); // #2
        lastFetch = timeService.UTCNow; // #3...
        logger.Info($"Updated on {timeService.Now}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        updateTask = null; // #3 ends
    }
}
```

So what *should* happen is when calling `Update`, it should return with a Task after `Update` hits `await updateFn()`. But it's completing as if `await updateFn()` is a synchronous call.

The issue with this unexpected behavior is that `updateTask = null` executes first, and then it is set to `updateTask = Update()` (the completed task). But I need the other way around to happen.

Note - this only happens sometimes. This is for a caching of network payloads, and other instances of this class work fine. it's just for one specific payload that it doesn't. the `updateFn` of that payload consists of multiple `await networkRequest`.

Comment: How do you know the order of execution? Using a Visual Studio debugger will not be reliable for tasks because pausing and resuming a process takes much longer than the execution of these Tasks.

Comment: To have a more reliable test I would recommend to make tasks slower by adding a few `await Task.Delay()` calls to make sure the Task cannot complete synchronously which is intended for cached value for example to reduce overhead.

Comment: The tasks might be sync [updateFn] and have no need for actual async, therefore it could be executed immediately.

Comment: If `updateFn()` runs synchronously then this is expected behaviour. Begs the questions: what is `updateTask` there for anyway, it seems unnecessary. If it is really needed then  `Get<TResult>` should manage it alone. By the way `catch (Exception e) {throw e;` what is that for? It will just wipe the stack trace. At the most, you should just do `throw;`

Comment: @Danitechnik @misticos @Charlieface 
I used logging to see the order of operations.
`updateFn` is essentially a network request, so it is never a synchronous function.
`updateTask` is there so if a subsequent call to `Get` happens while the initial `Get` is taking place, the subsequent call will `await updateTask`

Comment: Sorry I tried making a stripped-down example but it is clearly not enough context, I will update soon

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour, cause after `await` you are not returning any task, so the flow of the `Update()` method continues. that's why your #3 is in the `lastFetch` asignation line, not on the first line on `Get<TResult>`.

If you want to return and finish earlier, your Update method should look like this, assuming that `UpdateFn()` returns a Task too:

```
private async Task Update()
{
    try {
        return await updateFn(); // #2
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

You can also refactor your `Get<TResult>` method to be something like:

```
public async Task<TResult> Get<TResult>(bool force = false)
{
    return await Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Task that should execute asynchronously that is executing synchronously.

Asynchronous methods *may* execute asynchronously. They don't *have* to execute asynchronously. [Every `async` method begins executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as explained on my blog), and is only asynchronous if it `await`s a task that is not already complete. If it never `await`s or if it `await`s only already-completed tasks, then the method will run fully synchronously. This is normal behavior for C#.

*Ideally* you should structure the code so that `Update` isn't responsible for clearing its own returned task. I mean, that's kinda weird: a method is changing the variable holding the value *it already returned*. Something like this, maybe:

```
private T payload;
private Func<Task<T>> updateFn;
private Task updateTask = null;

public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(bool force = false)
{
  await UpdateAsync();
  return payload;
}

private async Task UpdateAsync()
{
  try {
    updateTask = DoUpdateAsync();
    await updateTask;
  } finally {
    updateTask = null;
  }

  static async Task DoUpdateAsync()
  {
    payload = await updateFn();
    lastFetch = timeService.UTCNow;
    logger.Info($"Updated on {timeService.Now}");
  }
}
```

This way, `UpdateAsync` both sets and clears `updateTask`, and the wrapped `DoUpdateAsync` just contains the logic.